# Converting pandas df column of values to uniqueidentifiers

Tags: python, pandas, function, uniqueidentifier

I have two pandas dataframes which look like this:

```
df1
            node_id        lat       long
0      [INET_N_855]  53.017810  23.896413
1     [INET_N_1828]  52.984994  22.241386
2      [INET_N_329]  52.881484  20.619795
3     [INET_N_1612]  46.505528  13.592806
4     [INET_N_1009]  46.503733  13.416054
...             ...        ...        ...
4670  [SEQ_12031_p]  49.697490  12.328040
4671      [NO_N_30]  59.272825   5.519794
4672   [INET_N_379]  35.828836  14.556524
4673  [INET_N_1287]  61.638170  21.398810
4674      [Prod_33]  64.982320   6.611590
[4675 rows x 3 columns]

df2
                         node_id  ...                    long
0      [INET_N_855, INET_N_1828]  ...  [23.896413, 22.241386]
1      [INET_N_1828, INET_N_329]  ...  [22.241386, 20.619795]
2     [INET_N_1612, INET_N_1009]  ...  [13.592806, 13.416054]
3     [INET_N_1612, INET_N_1009]  ...  [13.592806, 13.416054]
4     [INET_N_1612, INET_N_1009]  ...  [13.592806, 13.416054]
...                          ...  ...                     ...
6318    [SEQ_6435_p, INET_N_379]  ...   [13.88715, 14.556524]
6319  [N_14_M_LMGN, INET_N_1287]  ...    [23.08042, 21.39881]
6320      [SEQ_12356_p, Prod_33]  ...     [6.755214, 6.61159]
6321  [N_261_M_LMGN, SEQ_2566_p]  ...    [25.34835, 25.25854]
6322  [N_261_M_LMGN, SEQ_2566_p]  ...    [25.34835, 25.25854]
[6323 rows x 3 columns]
```

`df2` column `'node_id'` is consisting items from `df1` column `'node_id'`. Sadly some of the items in `'node_id'` are too long. Therefore, these list items in `'node_id'` should be shortened to equal or less than 12 characters for inputing a simulation program.

To achieve this, I will need a `unique_identifier_generator(df1, df2)` function, which will convert the entries in `df1['node_id']` to some unique id equal/less than 12 characters, and also does the same thing to `df2['node_id']` with matching unique ids.

I think I can do the pandas element change part. However, I do not know how to create a `unique_identifier_generator` function.

Do you know what to use? or what python-package I should check? or maybe a simple way to generate unique ids from given string or given pandas Series?

Comment: Why is node_id a list in df1? Also what are the values in the lists, are they strings?

Comment: Don't know why. But it can be converted with `df['node_id'] = df['node_id'].apply(lambda x: x[0])`. And the second, the values in the list are strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this kind of sounds like something a hash-function could do, there are plenty of those in [python hashlib doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html)
but you should probably take one which does not have high collision weakness

besides that you could check out the [LabelEncoder from sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) which might be easier since collisions shouldn't occur there

basic example for adding an id:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

encoder = LabelEncoder().fit(df.node_id)
df["id"] = encoder.transform(df.node_id)
```

the id could be converted to string or something like that, but int may be more useful in some cases

conversion to str might look something like this:

```py
df["id"] = [f"node_{id}" for id in encoder.transform(df.node_id)]
```

Comment: Won't the hash functions create like `'0394a2ede332c9a13eb8'` entries? I would be happy if these ids could be more readable like `'AAAA_001'`

Comment: LabelEncoder could be but usefull. Maybe I can generate numbers and then put them as string next to `'AA_'` for example. BTW @Anton if you add an example of sklearn for documentation reasons, It would be good!